# Keep row and next one based on conditions - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I need to clean a dataset that is similar to the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMjuy.png

The expected result looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFJHS.png

In other words, I need to keep all rows that (1) have 'action' in the column 'ACTION' *and* the immediate next one - (2) if the next one has 'result' in that column.
I've tried several combination of `.shift()`, but it did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
df.assign(step=df['Action'].eq('action').cumsum())\
  .drop_duplicates(subset=['Action','step'], keep='first')\
  .groupby('step')\
  .filter(lambda x: x.step.count()==2)
```

Output:

```
    SESSION  Action  TIME  step
0         1  action   0.1     1
1         1  result   0.2     1
2         2  action   0.1     2
3         2  result   0.2     2
4         3  action   0.3     3
5         3  result   0.4     3
7         1  action   0.3     4
8         1  result   0.4     4
12        3  action   0.6     6
13        3  result   0.7     6
14        4  action   0.8     7
15        4  result   0.9     7
```